# The sdk update sites list is empty in my android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, sdk

I don't use it much and I downloaded it about 6 months ago for the purpose of learning. I don't know how to use it.
But I made sure to always have the latest version of android studio and the plugins.
the sdk update sites list was not empty before, but now finally I was trying to start learning flutter and how to use android studio, I found that sdk update sites list is empty and I can't update the sdk.
Is there a solution to this problem

[image]

Edit*
i have just updated to the latest version and still the same problem i have un installed and re-installed an older version and it worked, but once i apply the update the problem back again i have tried using vpn and still the same problem

Comment: what you mean empty? there is one item is there

Comment: There is only one out of 12
And I'm not getting any updates and I can't install anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the problem was in the system format language
I was using the Arabic language and it seems that it is no longer supported in the newer versions of Android Studio
I changed the language format to US English and the problem was solved

Comment: Yes it is! I was engage it many days. Thank you a lot bro.

Answer (score 0):

its depends on where are you from try to use vpn and try again

Comment: i have just tried a vpn to many country's like you said and it didn't work still no updates